# Terminal emulator with keyboard scroll-copy-paste

Tags: command-line, software-recommendation

There are many terminal emulators for Linux with different nice features, but I'm looking for a KEYBOARD scroll-back, copy and paste. Is there a terminal emulator capable of doing that?

Because running `tmux` everywhere and configuring `tmux` and `vim`/... to share a clipboard with each other and parent OS (over `ssh`?) is very frustrating, but all of this can be solved with this one feature.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about keyboard scrolling, but most emulators have keyboard copy and paste. You just need to press the shift key when you do the normal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

Comment: Right, but having to use mouse to select something in the first place is super annoying